# How to do full text search similar to "like '%search%' in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

We are trying to filter out some suspicious bogus fields in our database. And I think full text search is the way to go after I read some posts. However I found full text search does not work the way I expected. For example.

```
SELECT name FROM dbo.Account WHERE contains(Name, '"n/a"')
```

does not return anything

```
SELECT name FROM dbo.Account WHERE Name like '%n/a%'
```

returns two records

```
Name
Applimation, Inc. - N/A
n/a
```

Any idea how to make it work?

thanks

Comment: Are you setting up full text search to search on the right columns?

Comment: I set up one fulltext index on several columns like (Name, firstname, lastname, street, city, state, country). Didn't I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the reference handy, but the SQL Server fulltext engine does not index words that are too short (noise words) such as "a", "or".  It could possibly also include "n/a".

Another possibility is that the '/' is a word breaker in your particular language setup

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142509.aspx

Or you can check the fts stop list for a short phrase containing n/a to see if it will be indexed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280463.aspx

Comment: Thanks a million for the reference. I am using the default language setup, English as I checked. I will check the stop list to see whether it is included that.

Comment: I did find out that '"n/a"' is in the noise word category. Thanks again cyberkiwi for the help.